# nodejs express - big chunk is logged twice in res.on('data')

Tags: node.js, rest, express, chunks

I have an issue in nodeJS here which lies on async as far as I see but I am not able to handle it and I didn't find a solution to my specific problem.

I am currently implementing a server which polls data from another server every x seconds. I then use the data chunk of the response of the foreign server, which is a JSON-string, to recieve the necessary live-data and then parse and save them to my mongoDB.
The problem is that the chunk sometimes is pretty long since the server sometimes transmitts many lines.

Therefore sometimes my tool already works whenever the chunk is not too big, but sometimes it doesn't. After logging the chunk I noticed that in these cases the chunk is logged twice.

For example if the `res.data` looks like this: [1,"123"][9,"234"] (in real it is of course much bigger) I get logged:

chunk: [1,"123
chunk "][9,"234"]

And this destroys my `var response`, which then is `response: "][9,"234"]`.
Here is the important part of the code:

```
function pollUra() {
var response = '';
var deferred = Q.defer();

// Send a request to URAv2
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf-8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        // We need to set response to null here, because if there is too many data in the chunk,
        // the response concatenates chunk after chunk, while chunk is concatenated by its seperate parts.
        // chunk1 -> chunk1+chunk2 -> chunk1+chunk2+chunk3
        // response = chunk1 -> chunk1+chunk1+chunk2 -> chunk1+chunk1+chunk2+chunk1+chunk2+chunk3...
        console.log('chunk: '+chunk);
        response = '';
        response += chunk;


    });


    res.on('end', function () {
        var parsedResponseArray = parser.parseQuery(response);
    ...
    }
```

I thought that the soulition described in the comment solved the issue, because it then seemed to work most time, but now it seems like it was only luck that the chunk didn't become big enough for the failure for a longer time.

My wish was to just catch the chunk after it was send completely but I am somehow not able to find the solution, since I thought that `res.on('end')` is just called after the data chunk has been sended completely.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need the write the data to file  \ hold it in a dictionary. 
since everything is async what will happen when you get to such files at the same time? you have to somehow identify the the destination of each chunk and assign to the correct spot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the line `response = '';` inside of your `res.on('data'...`

Otherwise the code looks good, the problem is you reinitialize the `response` variable. As a result previously saved data chunk is erased each time the new is arrived.

---

Quoting you:

> For example if the res.data looks like this: [1,"123"][9,"234"] (in
>   real it is of course much bigger) I get logged:
>
> chunk: [1,"123 chunk "][9,"234"]

Notice that chunk 1 + chunk 2 = [1,"123"][9,"234"]

So, the code has to be the one you have, but without resetting `response` variable:

```
// Send a request to URAv2
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf-8');

    response = ''; // Reset variable in case it is not empty
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        // We need to set response to null here, because if there is too many data in the chunk,
        // the response concatenates chunk after chunk, while chunk is concatenated by its seperate parts.
        // chunk1 -> chunk1+chunk2 -> chunk1+chunk2+chunk3
        // response = chunk1 -> chunk1+chunk1+chunk2 -> chunk1+chunk1+chunk2+chunk1+chunk2+chunk3...
        console.log('chunk: '+chunk);
        response += chunk;


    });


    res.on('end', function () {
        var parsedResponseArray = parser.parseQuery(response);
    ...
    }
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't solve it, I already tried that out. It is definitely the res.on('data')-block which is invoked twice. I tested it with an iterator iterated in the data-block and if the data-chunk is big the iterator gets iterated by one. If not, it doesn't.
Therefore I could simply use two string, i.e. response1 and response2 and concatenate response2 with the second chunk if iter > 0, but I can't imagine that this should be the only way to solve this...

Comment: You are missing the point. It is a normal operation to have 'data' event trigger multiple times. That is the architecture of   TCP/IP protocol itself. You receive `data` twice (or more), if you summarize everything together, in the end you will see the full `data` you want.

Comment: Yes, I know that already, just tested it with iterator to be 100% sure where the problem lies. What I wanted to say is that if I am deleting var response from inside the function the failure still ocures.
But maybe to clarify this: I am then using a global variable at which I store the chunk. And then the failure still ocures even though the global variable should not be reinitialized. It's just the function pollUra() which is loope by setTimeout. And if I am parsing the chunk inside the data-block I of course get an error since my parser tries to parse each single part of the chunk.

Comment: Oh, got it. I  forgot to null response before the next server-polling. Thank you! Can't vote your answer up since I need 15 reputations. :(

Comment: "Oh, got it. I forgot to null response before the next server-polling. Thank you! Can't vote your answer up since I need 15 reputations. :( – " solves my problem but don't know the reason behind it